# drag & drop image outside and inside a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, drag-and-drop

In my project I'm having a scrollview with a view images inside. I'd like to drag them from my scroller to my View and counterwise.

Is there someone who has some experience with this type of function.

Answer (score 1):

In essence what you'll want to do it place a UIGestureRecognizer in each view you wish to drag. In the selector the recognizer calls, you need to handle each type of state in a switch statement, similar to the following:

```
- (void)handleDragging:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{    
    switch ([gestureRecognizer state]) 
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            [self startDragging:gestureRecognizer];
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            [self doDrag:gestureRecognizer];
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
            [self stopDragging:gestureRecognizer];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This will provide 3 entry points. I'd recommend in startDrag: that you remove the view from the scrollview (if it is inside one), and add it to the superview of everything, so that it's on top while dragging. In doDrag: you'll want to move the view's location to the location of the gesture. Finally, in stopDragging: you'll want to add the view to whichever view it is on top of (scrollview or otherwise) at the correct location.

Comment: Great detail on this answer. Fixed a couple of issues in my implementation.